# Blank map using Native Google Maps in Ionic2 - Correct keys

Tags: cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am brand new to Ionic, just started my first project with it. I'm trying to get google maps to display on a page right now, which I almost have. It's just [the map displays blank like so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhPSZ.png) The api is [definitely enabled on the google api console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISB36.png)  also, so it can't be that. However it's clear my app isn't generating any requests, which is odd because the fact that the map-controls are present means I must reaching the maps service okay?

I know blank maps can happen as a result of an incorrect api key but I have triple checked and the key I installed the cordova native google maps plugin with is correct. I have tried new keys, removing and reinstalling the plugin, and both methods combined, the same problem persists in all cases.

My implementation is lifted almost verbatim from a tutorial/ionic docs, so can't see that there'd be an issue there:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import {
 GoogleMap,
 GoogleMapsEvent,
 GoogleMapsLatLng,
 CameraPosition,
 GoogleMapsMarkerOptions,
 GoogleMapsMarker
} from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html'
})
export class ProfilePage {
  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  map: any;
  infowindow: any;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.loadMap();
        });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
   //this.loadMap();
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ProfilePage');
  }

  loadMap(){

        let location = new GoogleMapsLatLng(-34.9290,138.6010);

        this.map = new GoogleMap('map', {
          'backgroundColor': 'white',
          'controls': {
            'compass': true,
            'myLocationButton': true,
            'indoorPicker': true,
            'zoom': true
          },
          'gestures': {
            'scroll': true,
            'tilt': true,
            'rotate': true,
            'zoom': true
          },
          'camera': {
            'latLng': location,
            'tilt': 30,
            'zoom': 15,
            'bearing': 50
          }
        });

        this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).subscribe(() => {
            console.log('Map is ready!');
        });

    }

}
```

Any help appreciated; this is driving me nuts.

Comment: Is your API key specific to the domain you are accessing from?

Comment: Nope there's no domain, platform or any other restrictions on it at all.

Comment: Usually some API keys are specific to a domain and some API keys have the capability to add any desired domain. But there will be a restriction for Google API's regarding the accessing domain.

Comment: @Coder I can't see that there are any domain restrictions, not that I really would know how to check. But this is such a trivial feature that's been done thousands of times, surely if the Google maps API's had domain restrictions there would be loads of people with the same problem.

Comment: Anything in the logs/console? looks like you have wrong assumption about URLs

Comment: you are test the map on device ? google maps native can't test on browser

Comment: @MochammadTaufiq Yeah im aware of that much, I am testing it on both a real device and emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, even though I ensured through SDK manager that I had Google Play Services installed, as well as using an x86 image for the emulator as thats a requirement for Google Api v3 (or so I read), the emulator does not work with Play Services.

This is required for v3 Google API. Running on a real android 7 device works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Api Keys for google maps have URL Restrictions.

> To prevent a third party from using your client ID on their own
>   website, the use of your client ID is restricted to a list of URLs
>   that you specifically authorize.
>
> To see the URLs you have already authorized or to authorize additional
>   URLs:
>
> 1.Log in to the Google Cloud Support Portal.
>
> 2.In the left-hand menu, click Maps: Manage Client ID.

URLs are checked based on the Origin of the request and can be Development URLs such as http://localhost:8080

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've never seen or setup an account on the Cloud Support Portal, and haven't had any credentials produced for me, so have no idea how I would access that